# Which css class library goes well with Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

As title says, I want to know which css class can be paierd with angular material.
The purpose is to have simple classes just as column-md, row, paddings, margins, containers, avoiding confussion with the angular material classes.
I want to have just one css library to style things like colors and position and have my componens running well.
I thought that bootstrap could be a good pick, but I'm facing errors with the card styling because it conflicts with angular material cards.

I'm new to Angular, and when I was using Vue, we had a beautyful framework called Quasar (https://quasar.dev/) that brings components alongside with css classes, I want to have something similar in Angular but using Angular Material.

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO I’m afraid (opinion based). Having said that, I have good experience with https://open-props.style/

Comment: This solution is only for coloring, right? I need something that besides of coloring can help me use rows, columns, labels, tooltips and stuff.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.